# Looking for an automated method for headwater watershed delineation at county scale

Tags: arcgis-desktop, watershed, flow-accumulation

I am hoping to delineate watersheds, which are extremely small, across a large area.

My objective is to create a workflow that will delineate all head water catchments through an automated process. I am new to automation and coding, and my experience thus far has been with individual sites using the watershed tools (fill, flow accumulation, direction, etc.) in ArcMap.

These watersheds are uphill from head water streams, and these headwater streams are not represented by National Hydrography Dataset flowlines. NHD lines rarely reflect actual headwaters in my study area and so I am attempting to identify them myself. Below is an example of a headwater that has a larger than natural catchment due to storm water drainage. Ignore the blue line.

[image]

I would like to produce catchments at this scale across the entire county, and hopefully determine their change in size from hydrologic alterations, such as this one.

Is there an automated way to achieve this? I would be running an unrealistic amount of watershed functions through Model Builder to do it otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Unfortunately, Boolean "is it possible?" Questions are not likely to return a useful answer. Even the real question, "How is it possible..." doesn't mesh well with our Focused question/Best answer model, since we're more of a problem-solving site. It seems that an "unrealistic amount of watershed functions" is intrinsic to your task, whether through ModelBuilder or Python, but there a number of hydrological modeling toolsets out there to be researched.

Comment: Most 'automation' can be done using depression break from Whitebox, but it doesn't account for stormwater pipes, results can be random. So, request culverts dataset and burn your LiDAR DEM(s) using these lines.